# Python Conversion from int to Windows-1252

Tags: python

I am currently writing a program that reads data from a serial port adds some header information then writes this data to a .jpg file.

I require to write to the file in Windows-1252 encoding format, yes the method in which I construct the data and the header is in hexadecimal format.

I realised my problem when comparing the picture that should be written and what was actually written, and saw that DOULBE LOW 9 QUOTES were not written as quotes but rather as a zero.

The decimal code for that symbol is `132 (0x84)`. If I use `chr(0x84)` I get the following error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character `\x84` in position 0: character maps to

Which only makes sense if `chr()` was trying to map to Latin-1 codeset. I have tried to convert the int to a unicode but from my research chr is the only function that does this.

I have also tried to use the `struct` package in python.

```
import struct
a = 123;
b = struct.pack("c",a)
print(b)
```

I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 3, in
>    struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1

Reading past questions, answers and documentation does get quite confusing as there is a mix of python2 and python3 answers mixed in with people converting to ascii (which obviously wouldn't work).

I am using Python 3.4.3 (the latest version) on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Have you tried to use the struct module? https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: @danielfranca Yes I have. Will update question with what I have tried with struct.

Comment: Try `a = bytes([123])`. Result I get is `b'{'`.

Comment: @martineau Try bytes([132]), what do you get?

Comment: If I `print(a)` afterwards, I get `b'\x84'`, and 0x84 == 132 (and `a[0]` is also 132).

Answer (score 1):

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character \x84`

`\x84` is the encoding of the lower quotes character in Windows-1252. This suggests your data is already encoded, and you should not try to encode it again. In a text string the quote should show up as `"\u201E"`. `"\u0084"` (the result of `chr(132)`) is actually a [control character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/84/index.htm).

You should have either bytes which you can *decode* to a string:

```
>>> b"\x84".decode('windows-1252')
'\u201e'
```

Or you should have a text string, which you can *encode* to a byte string

```
>>> "\u201e".encode('windows-1252')
b'\x84'
```

If you read data from somewhere you could use the `struct` module like this

```
# suppose we download some data:
data=b'*\x00\x00\x00abcde'

a, txt = struct.unpack("I5s", data)
print(txt.decode('windows-1252'))
```

Comment: I can guarantee that it was not already bytes. I was literally doing chr(132) and that is all.

Comment: @LanceHenderson `chr(132)` can't be encoded using windows-1252. The [DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201E/index.htm) has Unicode code point 0x210E, so the code to get this character is `chr(0x210E)` or `chr(8462)`. 132 is the encoding of that character using windows-1252.